# How can I get MAX() field in a sqlite table using additional condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

There is the following table structure in sqlite:

```
==========================
| Id | Name | Date       |
==========================
| 1  | Foo  | 2021-01-01 |
--------------------------
| 2  | Foo  | 2021-01-02 |
--------------------------
| 3  | Foo  | 2021-01-03 |
--------------------------
| 4  | Bar  | 2021-01-01 |
--------------------------
| 5  | Bar  | 2021-01-02 |
==========================
```

and I need to implement the following logic in one query (pseudocode):

```
$names = 'SELECT name FROM MyTable'

for ($name in $names) {
  $fields = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name = :name'
  $id = getIdWithBiggestDate($fields)
}
```

As a result, I should get something like this (items with the unique names and maximum dates):

```
==========================
| Id | Name | Date       |
==========================
| 3  | Foo  | 2021-01-03 |
--------------------------
| 5  | Bar  | 2021-01-02 |
==========================
```

Is it possible to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite you can do it with this non-standard SQL query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name
```

This works in SQLite because a column like `Id` which does not appear in the `group by` clause and also it is not aggregated ([*bare*](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) column) is returned from the row that contains the max `Date`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=58341709eb755dfd4050410c84d80d94).

Comment: No, I need a max date, but not a max id

Comment: @proninyaroslav fine, it is the same logic. I edited.

Comment: @mins Yes, it seems to work. Thank you. There is a small problem with this: I use DAO to access the database, and my entity fields are non-nullable. If the DB is empty, `SELECT Id, Name, MAX(Date)` will return entities with null fields. This would not have happened if I had used `SELECT *`.  Is there an alternative query that uses `SELECT *`?  even if it's clumsy, it will suit me.

Comment: @proninyaroslav if the table is empty the query returns nothing. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=70b2b6fe80d471ae8ac4e0b5a446aac9

Comment: @mins yes, it shows empty columns, but in my case this will set null in every column. This is the DAO logic, that I'm using

Comment: @proninyaroslav the result is not empty columns. It is an empty resultset. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=776d8457ee3b6b658da19b3fdc158c76 for other possible solutions which all return empty resultsets.

Comment: I once used `SELECT *, max(field)` and this returned null on the columns.  I think this is a feature or a bug of the DAO library, so I used an alternative query with `SELECT * ... WHERE field = (SELECT max(field) ...)`

Comment: @proninyaroslav `SELECT *, max(field)...` would return null columns if you do not use `GROUP BY...`. With `GROUP BY...` it does not return empty columns if the table is empty.

Comment: Awesome. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Name,Date 
from MyTable
where 
(Name,Date) in (select Name,max(Date) from MyTable group by Name)
```

Comment: `select max(Date)` will select ONE max date from all rows. In my case, I need to select the max dates from those rows that have a unique `Name`, that is, there can be several of them.  I have displayed this in an example.

Comment: @proninyaroslav I've edited my answer, initially I could not understand what you needed